# Unable to add Crash Reporter to iphone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I have been trying all night to get PLCrashReporter into my app prior to release. I have followed the instructions on github to the letter but keep getting "can't find crashreporter/crashreporter.h" when i try to go and build. This of course leads to about 54 other build errors.

I know the error must be in xcode finding the headers but for the life of me I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I have even commented out the crashreporter code in my appdelegate and still get the problem.

I have moved the framework all over my directory structure and added the folder to my header/frameworks/library search paths all with no luck.

I did try to build the demo project on github but have the same issues with that as well

Anyone have any luck with this and can let me know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Prasanth, Did you implement PLCrashReporter in your project. Can you please share some steps how to integrate in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `PLCrashReporter` headers path to your project. In Xcode 3.x, look for the **`User Headers Path`**.

Comment: thanks..this is what I had to do in xcode 4 for it to build:
1. I had to add  framework search path "$(SRCROOT)/" with recursive on to the build settings.  
Also I had to add:
2. #import "CrashReportSender.h" to my appdelegate.h file(instead of the .m as the instructions recommend)
3. finally I had to add CrashReportSenderDelegate into my @interface declaration for the appdelegate
so it looked like this:
@interface projectAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CrashReportSenderDelegate>